# How to get the convert the Class object of a primitive type to it's wrapper's Class

Tags: java, reflection

I'm working with reflection read and writing objects.  I have the problem that I am reading in primitive types; but want to tell the read method to read them as their wrapper (so read a char as a Char).  It seems as if there should be a simple static method I can call which would take the primitive Class and return it's wrapper's Class.  so for example I could provide char.class and get the Char object's class returned.

I know it's easy enough to hard code this, but that looks ugly; and it seems like this would come up common enough to be worth Sun including a static helper method.  I've looked and can't seem to find it, but I still find it hard to believe the method doesn't exist.  Can anyone point me to the name of the method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be nothing in the JDK, but there's the [Primitives](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html) class in Guava, which allows you to write:

```
Primitives.wrap(char.class)
```

to get `Character.class`.

Answer (score 0):

In the JDK's tools.jar there's is `typeUtils.boxedClass(primitive.type)` which deals with `Symbol` objects. I know it's not what you want, but I'll throw it in for reference and in case what you look for is actually around it.